# Did Admob remove the test adUnitID on iOS?

Tags: ios, admob

I went through a dozen of my apps and It seems that the test adUnitID provided by Admob in their documentation doesn't seems to work anymore and the ads will not show unless you provide an adUnitID generated for publishing.(from Admob dashboard).

Please is this happening for other people or am I missing some new changes that Admob recently made to load test ads?

This is the admob test ID and I code that used to work:
self.bannerView.adUnitID = @"ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716";

PS. The banner test ID was working yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

yes, same for me for test ads using the provided adUnitID (ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/2934735716)... a real id works, but of course is not recommended for dev... also using a real ID along with test devices specified does not seem to work for me either. Appears that only a real ID that shows real ads is working at the moment... go figure?

--> UPDATE: started working again for me this morning (2-8-16)...

Comment: Still they don't work for me! Please if there is someone that have the same issue and figured out a way to make test ads appears please let us know.
We can't test on test IDs or test devices.The ads don't show! How can we test our banners ads if they works or not if the ads don't show at all. If we go with a real ad ID we risk false impressions and account closure.Any one helps.Thanks